# Can't jump into closure in debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, eventemitter

I'm try read source of [EventEmitter](https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter). 
I want jump into closure `aliasClosure()` which is defined in function `alias(name)`

```
function alias(name) {
    return function aliasClosure() {
        return this[name].apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Also:

```
proto.on = alias('addListener');
```

I write little script

```
var ee = new EventEmitter();
function l() {
  console.log('Test');
}

ee.on('foo', l);

ee.emitEvent('foo');
```

and set breakpoint on line `ee.on('foo', l);` After F11 in FireBug I'm awaiting jump into `return this[name].apply(this, arguments);` But I get error message in console:

> Resuming debugger: error during debugging loop: TypeError:
>   firstViewRangeElement is null

If I set breakpoint on line `return this[name].apply(this, arguments);`
 debugger skip (don't stop) this breakpoing.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try `step into`, try chrome's debugger, try opera dragonfly, try native debugger in firefox 25.

Comment: That's a bug in FireBug.

Comment: In chrome it works as expected. It's Firebug bug. Thanks!